# i wont to install voltdb on ubuntu 32 bit version

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

can any one help me to install voltdb on ubuntu 32 bit version
 i have following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/voltdb/VoltDB

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.voltdb.VoltDB

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VoltDB is only available for 64-bit operating systems.  You can run it on Linux (development and production) or Mac OSX (development only).